# PHP if ( $some_var == 1 ) always returns true even if it's not true?

Tags: php, variables, comparison

This issue is simple, but I am not sure what is the best approach to get around it.

If the variable contains a number, how can I make sure that the if statement only returns true if indeed the `$some_var` is one?

Comment: Can you post some code (with sample values of `$some_var`) showing the issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHP is a loosely typed language which means values can change their type depends on the context. When a loose comparison is used, 1 is treated equal to true, as well as any non-empty string.

you need to use 3 equals if you want to compare taking into account the variable type.

```
if($some_var === 1){
```

here is more info http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @Johny hmmm, actually I tried that and it still didn't seem to work. I'll try again.

Comment: post the code u have including where you apply the value to $some_val

Comment: JIC : Its a strict comparison.

Answer (score 9):

The number 1 is a shortcut for "true". In order to specify that it must actually be true, you want to use a triple equals operator. This makes sure it matches both value and type (1 and integer, respectively).

```
$some_var = 1;
$other_var = "1";

$some_var === 1; // True
$other_var === 1; // False
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if($some_var === 1) //checks also type
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you should be using ===, but the downside of that is its going to check for both value and type. This should be fine if you want to check for 1 as an integer. But since 1 could also be a string value (data submitted by forms are always strings), your === comparison might fail. Try this instead:

```
if ($my_var == 1 && is_numeric($my_var)) {

    echo 'My condition is true. Woo hoo!';
}
```

Comment: `is_numeric($my_var)` is checking the type

Comment: @JohnnyCraig is_numeric does check type, only whether the input is "numeric". From the PHP doc:
`is_numeric — Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string`