# OpenCart hide section on pages > 1

Tags: php, opencart

I have descriptional section on catalog pages of my OpenCart site. This section must be shown **only on the first page**. It seems to be a simple task but my code doesn't work

**category.php**

```
if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
        $page = $this->request->get['page'];
} else { 
        $page = 1;
}
```

**category.tpl**

```
<?php if ($description && $page == 1) { ?>
        <section>
            <div class="category-info">
                <h1><?php echo $h1; ?></h1>
                <div><?php echo $description; ?></div>
            </div>
        </section>
<?php } ?>
```

My code hides section on the all pages.

**UPD**

My condition `$page == 1` works but for some reason `$page` is not defined in `catalog.tpl` despite the fact that I defined it in `catalog.php`. So I defined it again in `catalog.tpl` and code now works. It is not supercorrect solution, but it works.

Comment: Where are you setting `$description`? Are you sure it isn't null?

Comment: I'm sure because without condition `($page == 1)` description is shown on every catalog page

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP if ( $some\_var == 1 ) always returns true even if it's not true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188749/php-if-some-var-1-always-returns-true-even-if-its-not-true)

Comment: I tried to `print_r($page)` and it returns: "Notice: Undefined variable: page in /hosting/home/../template/product/category.tpl on line 91" Why is it undefined??

Comment: So, I added the code defining `$page` from controller to `category.tpl` and now it works (not very elegant). But why it is not working from controller??..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one at **category.tpl**

```
<?php
    $show=1; if(isset($_GET['page'])){ if($_GET['page']!=1){ $show=0; }}
    if($show){ ?>
    <?php if ($description) { ?>
      <section>
        <div class="category-info">
          <h1><?php echo $h1; ?></h1>
          <div><?php echo $description; ?></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    <?php } ?>
```

What code does is. It will show for category page when there is no page number and page number equals to 1. Other than that it hides.
To show you h1 and description, description should be inserted as per your code. Hope you know it.

If you want to show you h1 always then keep the h1 outside the if statement.
Hope it fulfills your requirement